# Browser addon for copying text blocks from a file to multiple inputs

Tags: web-browser, chrome, firefox, copy-paste

I need to enter multiple bank account numbers in raw text to multiple inputs in a bank website. For example, I've got one account number in a file, following this format:

xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx

And I've got four inputs in the site. As for now, I need to copy-paste each of the blocks in each of the inputs.

Is there any browser-addon/OS-tool in order to perform this task? I use Linux Mint and Firefox, but I wouldn't mind using Chrome/Chromium.

It seems there are [JS workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804064/pasting-multiple-numbers-over-multiple-input-fields) provided already, but just wondering if there's a ready to use tool.

Answer (score 2):

Would the [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) browser extension work for you?

This would require you to write JavaScript, but it's pretty handy.

Here's an example script I would write to fill the 'Mickey Mouse' fields on [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';


    document.getElementsByName('firstname').forEach(v => v.value = "Hello");
    document.getElementsByName('lastname').forEach(v => v.value = "World");
})();
```

Then, one of the things you can also do, is use TamperMonkey to add your own 'overlay' on the page you are on, to add an interactive control panel, if that's the kind of functionality you need.

Comment: Thanks! There are other extensions such as GreaseMonkey, but I just wanted to know if there is some specific tool/extension for this instead of having to script it myself.